# Styling data points with smiley face markers

Tags: plotting

I would like to know how to make a smiley face in *Mathematica*.

Comment: `Style["\[HappySmiley]", 100]` ?

Comment: You can use `PlotMarkers` option in `ListPlot`, e.g. for `dat== RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}];` Try: `ListPlot[dat, PlotMarkers -> {Style[\[HappySmiley], Red], 40}]`

Comment: See on WDP [Search results for "smiley"](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=smiley)

Comment: See on Alpha [smiley plane curve](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=smiley+plane+curve)

Answer (score 4):

Well, obviously you need to just plot the equation of a smiley face:

```
Show[Plot[y /. #, {x, -12, 12}, PlotPoints -> 100] & /@ 
  Solve[
  (x^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 - 4/10 x^2 y - 163/4 (x^2 + y^2) + y^4 - y^3 + 25 y + 1575/4) ((x + 3)^2 + (y - 7)^2 -1) ((x - 3)^2 + (y - 7)^2 - 1) ((x)^2 + (y - 2)^2 - 64) == 0, 
  y], ImageSize -> 500, Axes->False, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1,PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Comment: For `10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)`, the option `PlotRange -> All` is needed.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I have that setting in my `init.m`

Comment: Jason, the OP's question is a bit unclear, but going off the title it seems to ask how to style data points in a plot as smiley faces, rather than just plotting a giant one. I'm not sure that this is a direct answer to the OP's question then. Perhaps you could include a solution for the data marker problem as well which has been proposed in comments, just to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't really tell what he was asking.  If that's what he wants, the answer was given in the comments to his question.  I just thought this was more interesting :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm making ubpdqn's suggestion an answer.

```
ListPlot[Table[n^(1/p), {p, 4}, {n, 10}], PlotMarkers -> Style["\[HappySmiley]", 25]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]